# If two checkboxes are checked - change background color

Tags: jquery, checkbox

This seems simple enough, but I'm not getting it to work. I am trying to validate if there are two checkboxes checked within a certain `div`. If they are, make the background red. I realize that the way I have it setup, all the `div`'s with the class `edit-container` will show red. I had not yet figured out how to cache this as the parent div of the checkbox.

```
<form action="">
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <p class="edit-title">Edit Preferences</p>
    <div class="edit-container">
        <label for="">Yes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check1" />
        <label for="">No</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check2" />
    </div>
    <div class="edit-container">
        <label for="">Yes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check1" />
        <label for="">No</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if (('.check1:checked,.check2:checked').length === 2) {
        $('.edit-container').css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using radio buttons?

Comment: No, in my particular case I need checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.edit-container').removeClass('red').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length === 2) $(this).closest('.edit-container').addClass('red');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vh2B5/)**

Since Madbreaks didn't like my answer, I'll explain it. Upon clicking any checkbox, a class (e.g. red) is removed from the parent (.edit-container) div. Then the checked child inputs are counted and if there are two, a class (red) is added to the parent div.

Comment: Your rep is massive, so humbly: I don't think long, one-line code solutions w/ no explanation are especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing $ for the jQuery selector statement in the true part of the IF clause. I have created a fiddle for it, fixed and handled to revert back if one of them is unchecked.

http://jsfiddle.net/3DPLd/2/

```
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var container=$(this).parent('.edit-container');

    if(container.find('.check1:checked,.check2:checked').length==2)
        container.css('background','red');
    else
        container.css('background','');        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$` in your `if` statement.

To change the bg color of just the parent div, change

```
$('.edit-container').css("background-color", "red");
```

to

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Better still, toggle a `class` on the element rather than setting an (evil) inline style.

Instead of using hard-coded classes in your selector, just look for `:checked` checkboxes inside the parent:

```
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    if($parent.find(':checked') == 2)
        $parent.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```